# DomDocument class unable access domnode

Tags: php, html, parsing, domdocument

I dont parse this url: http://foldmunka.net

```
$ch = curl_init("http://foldmunka.net");

//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); //not necessary unless the file redirects (like the PHP example we're using here)
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
clearstatcache();
if ($data === false) {
  echo 'cURL failed';
  exit;
}
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$data = mb_convert_encoding($data, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "utf-8");
$data = preg_replace('/<\!\-\-\[if(.*)\]>/', '', $data);
$data = str_replace('<![endif]-->', '', $data);
$data = str_replace('<!--', '', $data);
$data = str_replace('-->', '', $data);
$data = preg_replace('@<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>@si', '', $data);
$data = preg_replace('@<style[^>]*?>.*?</style>@si', '', $data);

$data = mb_convert_encoding($data, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "utf-8");
@$dom->loadHTML($data);

$els = $dom->getElementsByTagName('*');
foreach($els as $el){
  print $el->nodeName." | ".$el->getAttribute('content')."<hr />";
  if($el->getAttribute('title'))$el->nodeValue = $el->getAttribute('title')." ".$el->nodeValue;
  if($el->getAttribute('alt'))$el->nodeValue = $el->getAttribute('alt')." ".$el->nodeValue;
  print $el->nodeName." | ".$el->nodeValue."<hr />";
}
```

I need *sequentially* the alt, title attributes and the simple text, but this page i cannot access the nodes within the body tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with DomDocument and DOMXPath. It is much shorter and runs much faster (~100ms against ~2300ms) than the other solution with Simple HTML DOM Parser.

```
<?php

function makePlainText($source)
{
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHtmlFile($source);

    // use this instead of loadHtmlFile() to load from string:
    //$dom->loadHtml('<html><title>Hello</title><body>Hello this site<img src="asdasd.jpg" alt="alt attr" title="title attr"><a href="open.php" alt="alt attr" title="title attr">click</a> Some text.</body></html>');

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

    $plain = '';

    foreach ($xpath->query('//text()|//a|//img') as $node)
    {
        if ($node->nodeName == '#cdata-section')
            continue;

        if ($node instanceof DOMElement)
        {
            if ($node->hasAttribute('alt'))
                $plain .= $node->getAttribute('alt') . ' ';
            if ($node->hasAttribute('title'))
                $plain .= $node->getAttribute('title') . ' ';
        }
        if ($node instanceof DOMText)
            $plain .= $node->textContent . ' ';
    }

    return $plain;
}

echo makePlainText('http://foldmunka.net');
```

Comment: If someone knows how to filter out the cdata-section with the xpath query, please comment it.

Comment: @styu I have looked as per your request, but I dont understand the OP's question. You can try passing the option `LIBXML_NOCDATA` to your `load` call. Since the scraped page is valid XHTML, you also might want to use the XML parser instead of the HTML parser.

Comment: @Gordon: turbod clarified at [Pekka's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735291/domdocument-class-unable-access-domnode/2735318#2735318) that he wants to make a plain text version of the site, including the `title` and `alt` attributes of the `a` and `img` tags. As I see, with `load()` it isn't working as expected, but I don't know why (it is not extracting the attributes in this case).

Comment: @Gordon: Is there any advantage of using `load()` instead of `loadHtml()`?

Comment: `loadHtml` and `loadHtmlFile` will make `DOM` use the [HTML parser module](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-HTMLparser.html) instead of the XML parser module. Basically, you trade the ability to parse broken HTML for a certain degree of control over the markup you would have when using the XML parser. But dont ask me for details. In general, when you have valid XHTML, do not use the HTML parser. HTML is based on SGML. XHTML is based on XML.

Comment: @Gordon Thanks for the info (and for your continuous assistance), I will look after these things.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I'm getting what this script does - the replace operations look like an attempt at sanitation but I'm not sure what for, if you're just extracting some parts of the code -  but have you tried the [Simple HTML DOM Browser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)? It may be able to handle the parsing part more easily. Check out the examples.

Comment: I need the plaintext and the alt and title attributes. example: <html><title>Hello</title><body>Hello this site<img src="asdasd.jpg" alt="alt attr" title="title attr"><a href="open.php" alt="alt attr" title="title attr">click</a> Some text.</body></html>
I need this output: Hello Hello this site alt attr title attr alt attr title attr click Some Text.

Comment: @turbod The Simple HTML DOM browser can do both. The plaintext should be something like `$html->find("body",0)->plaintext` see the examples on the site to see how to run through a list of all tags to get their `alt` and `title` atributes.

Comment: Yes now I read the examples, but I can not find how to do it.
I need the plaintext and the alt and title attributes same time.

Comment: print file_get_html('http://foldmunka.net')->plaintext;
This print the plaintext, but the alt and the title attributes no.

Comment: @turbod aahh I see now, you need this *sequentially*. I didn't understand that. Whew, that's going to be more difficult, I have no solution ready for that, sorry. I'll leave my answer in place to prevent others from making the same mistake. You should edit your example into your answer to make this clear.

Comment: @Pekka It's a quite old question but here is my two separate answer, one with Simple HTML DOM Parser and a better one with DomDocument and DomXpath.

Comment: Simple HTML DOM is convenient, but very slow in comparison and has memory problems (http://sourceforge.net/search/?group_artifact_id=1044037&type_of_search=artifact&group_id=218559&words=memory).  If you're going to be handling more than 10 documents, or a very large one, I'd stick with DOMDocument.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [Simple Html DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) solution just for comparison. It's output is similar for the [DomDocument solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735291/php-domdocument-class-unable-access-domnode/4230447#4230447)'s, but this one is more complicated and runs much slower (~2300ms against DomDocument's ~100ms), so I **don't recommend** to use it:

**Updated** to work with `<img>` elements inside `<a>` elements.

```
<?php
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
// we are needing this because Simple Html DOM Parser's callback handler
// doesn't handle arguments
static $processed_plain_text = '';

define('LOAD_FROM_URL', 'loadfromurl');
define('LOAD_FROM_STRING', 'loadfromstring');

function callback_cleanNestedAnchorContent($element)
{
    if ($element->tag == 'a')
        $element->innertext = makePlainText($element->innertext, LOAD_FROM_STRING);
}

function callback_buildPlainText($element)
{
    global $processed_plain_text;

    $excluded_tags = array('script', 'style');

    switch ($element->tag)
    {
        case 'text':
            // filter when 'text' is descendant of 'a', because we are
            // processing the anchor tags with the required attributes
            // separately at the 'a' tag,
            // and also filter out other unneccessary tags
            if (($element->parent->tag != 'a') && !in_array($element->parent->tag, $excluded_tags))
                $processed_plain_text .= $element->innertext . ' ';
            break;
        case 'img':
            $processed_plain_text .= $element->alt . ' ';
            $processed_plain_text .= $element->title . ' ';
            break;
        case 'a':
            $processed_plain_text .= $element->alt . ' ';
            $processed_plain_text .= $element->title . ' ';
            $processed_plain_text .= $element->innertext . ' ';
            break;
    }
}

function makePlainText($source, $mode = LOAD_FROM_URL)
{
    global $processed_plain_text;

    if ($mode == LOAD_FROM_URL)
        $html = file_get_html($source);
    elseif ($mode == LOAD_FROM_STRING)
        $html = str_get_dom ($source);
    else
        return 'Wrong mode defined in makePlainText: ' . $mode;

    $html->set_callback('callback_cleanNestedAnchorContent');

    // processing with the first callback to clean up the anchor tags
    $html = str_get_html($html->save());
    $html->set_callback('callback_buildPlainText');

    // processing with the second callback to build the full plain text with
    // the required attributes of the 'img' and 'a' tags, and excluding the
    // unneccessary ones like script and style tags
    $html->save();

    $return = $processed_plain_text;

    // cleaning the global variable
    $processed_plain_text = '';

    return $return;
}

//$html = '<html><title>Hello</title><body>Hello <span>this</span> site<img src="asdasd.jpg" alt="alt attr" title="title attr"><a href="open.php" alt="alt attr" title="title attr">click <span><strong>HERE</strong></span><img src="image.jpg" title="IMAGE TITLE INSIDE ANCHOR" alt="ALTINACNHOR"></a> Some text.</body></html>';

echo makePlainText('http://foldmunka.net');
//echo makePlainText($html, LOAD_FROM_STRING);
```