# PHP to retrieve title from a webpage

Tags: php, curl

I have a PHP code to retrieve the title in a webpage. However, I cannot access this specific website(fine for other website) for some reason(no respond from the server). Why is this happening to only this website? What other method should I use? I tried cURL but still can't access the webpage.

This is my code:

```
<?php

function page_title($url) {

    $page = @file_get_contents($url);

    if (!$page) return null;

    $matches = array();

    if (preg_match('/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/', $page, $matches)) {
        return $matches[1];
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}


echo page_title('http://www.alibaba.com/');

?>
```

It came out: 
Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.alibaba.com): failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in C:\xampp\htdocs\myPHP\index.php on line 16.
Thanks!

Comment: Define "can't access the webpage"

Comment: What happens if you remove the @ in front of `file_get_contents()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get title of website via link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348912/get-title-of-website-via-link)

Comment: @Reeno Same warning came out.

Comment: because your ip is not allowed to access the alibab.com via `curl` or `file_get_contents` on the server of alibaba.com

Comment: @SKRocks but i can access the website(via web browser) but just not in php codings

Comment: @Cael try the answer of FrenchBarbu you will get your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set user_agent

```
$page = file_get_contents($url,false,stream_context_create(array("http" => array("user_agent" => "any"))));
```