# Embedding content from user submitted URL

Tags: javascript, php

I am developing a PHP based website. I would like to grab the web page title, content and thumb from any URL submitted by a user. I am not sure how I should proceed. If possible I would like to avoid any third party platform such as Embed. Could you please help?
Cheers.

Comment: I think you are looking for this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348912/get-title-of-website-via-link

Answer (score 0):

You must get source of entered web url.
And parse it with regex.
For get source code:

```
file_get_contents();
```

After use regex parse:

```
preg_match();
```

**detail of functions:**

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php
- http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_file_get_contents.asp